# PWM (4xM matrices) to Sequence Logo Visualizations in MATLAB or Python

Tags: rna-seq, python, visualization, motifs, matlab

Is there a MATLAB, or else Python (not R) tool for visualizing sequence Logos from probability weight matrices (PWMs)?

This seems like a basic and simple tool to implement, yet just above the threshold in the space of tedious to write my own from scratch - I was surprised I couldn't find a basic function like a

```
visualizePWM(pwm_matrix)
```

that would take a pwm_matrix that is a (4 by m) matrix and spit out the visualization of an m-length sequence motif/logo like:

[image]

I see all kinds of over-complicated bloated tools that I thought I ask in case I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

*answer from @M__, converted from [comments](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):*

This has been answered on stackoverflow using matplotlib for seq logo plot:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615527/sequence-logos-in-matplotlib-aligning-xticks

IMO its only useful for presentation, pretty pictures, thus there's no need for someone to write a library (which is what you're asking). If I'm using a mutation matrix (which I do), I want the raw numbers and significance values I don't want pretty graphs getting in the way.

Conceptually you would move from 2D to 1D, without subplots (which is doable), i.e. its a matrix. My view on code availability is not universal. I've had requests for separate CLIs (useful for someone clearly) ... which just never happened.

Comment: The solution proposed in the link is focused primarily on a tool that is captured as the pyseqlogo packet at the end. I have spent a good part of the day trying install the packet and get it to work, but to no avail it's failed with too many errors and complications to list :(.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and trial and error, located possibly the optimal tool for my question:

**seqlogo**

https://github.com/betteridiot/seqlogo

Surprisingly not only seqlogo is an elegant and minimal solution in Python (and R) I have discovered it has a relative implementation in MATLAB! It installed and worked the first try - beautiful output with all the output options I needed - rock solid.

**Python** one liner (not counting the example pwm input generation)

random_ppm = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(4), size=16)

ppm = seqlogo.Ppm(random_ppm)

**seqlogo.seqlogo(ppm  ,format='png',filename='out.png')**

Produces the following ('out.png')

[image]

And here is **MATLAB** Port:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/seqlogo.html

[image]